# How to check whether x => (id == null || id == x) is a tautology x => true?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

For `id = null`, my expression `x => (id == null || x == id)` should be considered as a tautology `x => true`.

As I am not knowledgeable in `Expression` my  code below fails to detect the tautology correctly. The program output says that it is `not tautology`.

#### Question:

What is the proper way to detect it?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

int? id = null;


Expression<Func<int, bool>> criteria = x => (id == null || x == id);
Expression<Func<int, bool>> tautology = x => true;


if (ExpressionEqualityComparer.Instance.Equals(criteria, tautology))
    Console.WriteLine("tautology");
else
    Console.WriteLine("not tautology");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The code you're using simply checks if the expressions are equivalent to each other _in terms of parameters and the code_.  Tautology is NP-complete. `ExpressionEqualityComparer` is not going to figure that out.

Comment: You can use Microsoft's [Nuqleon.Linq.Expressions.Optimizers](https://reaqtive.net/documentation/nuqleon/nuqleon.linq.expressions.optimizers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can mean the same thing it does not make the expressions equal. You can check [the sources](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/97783f52b2aaad8c70b153530d84b3ca4b821e85/src/EFCore/Query/ExpressionEqualityComparer.cs) of `ExpressionEqualityComparer` yourself - it compares expression without optimization/reduction as is. And the compiler generated expression trees will definitely will [be different](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI6oFEAPABwCcBTAZyswHtsqBuWHAFwH5FMATRAXkTYArgBtRLGLFjFy1WgwA8IAKyL2AGkQAjOnVEA+A4gDGZTGwrmAhgMREBxgBS8BgkeMTBg9t9x4AlJKylDT02Mpqmjp6hsZs1sJs+nQA5gCedg788WTCFJLSMEA==).